# Python JSON-file-reading generator (multi-line)

Tags: python, json, generator, multiline

I have a bunch of json files with multiple lines who look like this:

file1

```
{"id":1,"name":"Eric","height":1.80, ...},
{"id":2,"name":"Bob","height":1.90, ...}   
...
```

file2

```
{"id":3,"name":"Jenny","height":1.50, ...},
{"id":4,"name":"Marlene","height":1.60, ...} 
...
```

I want to build a generator to yield each line as a dictionary. My current code:

```
from typing import Iterator, Dict, Any, Optional
import io
import os

def json_gen2(file_list: list) -> Iterator[Dict[str, Any]]:
    import json
    for file in file_list:    
        with open(file) as json_file: 
            data = []
            for line in json_file:
                data = json.load(line)
                if not data:
                    break
                yield data

datapath = os.path.normcase(os.getcwd()) + '/data/log_data'
file_list = get_files(datapath) # create path list of json files
jsonfile = json_gen2(file_list)
next(jsonfile)
```

i get the following 
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cx2On.png)

pls help :)

Comment: Any reason you are doing this rather than reading the file line by line and on the string using the "loads" function from the json module?

Comment: i have multiple files who each have multiple lines. Is there a better way to get each line generated as a dictionary? :)

Comment: Try changing your `json.load(line)` to `json.loads(line)`

Comment: THX, Kurt Kline!!!! that was the solution :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, I misread. You are doing the same thing I was saying. Your error is due to using 'load' instead of 'loads'. Each line returned by

```
for line in json_file:
    data = json.load(line)
```

is a string, and you're attempting to read it as a file pointer.